# Gflop vendor specification vs practical results

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I have a questions that i can't i can't figure out.
I have a Nvidia GPU 750M and from specification it say it should have 722.7 GFlop/s. ([GPU specification](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/2224/geforce-gt-750m)) but when i try the test from CUDA samples give me about 67.64 GFlop/Sec.

Why such a big difference?
Thanks.

Comment: What test are you exactly running? and how are you measuring the FLOP. There aren't that many algorithms/optimised implementations that will attain peak FLOP. Also There can be a huge 3-10 times difference between single precision and double precision benchmarks, with the latter performing poorer.

Comment: I have try the sample from 0_Sample/Matrix_Muland also i ahve seen some example where was tested single precision and double precision. Why is a difference between single,double precision? How size of a variable has impact on GFlop?

Comment: @fhffhf They need different unit to compute. And there are less ALU's for double precision than for single precision per SM.

Comment: Ok @BlueWanderer, but one more question. I have try CUDAZ (http://cuda-z.sourceforge.net/) and for GFLOP it give me something like this: single precision: 660 GFlop/s, double precision : 31 Gflop/s and also for 32 bit integer : 32. Why is such a big difference between what give cuda samples and the result from CUDAZ? Thank you guys :)

Comment: @fhffhf It would be crazy for me to look into the implementation of it... :|

Comment: @BlueWanderer I understand, i was thinking maybe is something more 
obvious. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The peak performance can only be achieved when every core is busy executing `FMA` on every cycle, which is **impossible in a real task**.

Apart from no other operation is counted as 2 operations like `FMA`,

For a single kernel launch, if you do some sampling in Visual Profiler you will notice there is something called `stall`. Each operation takes time to finish. And if another operation relies on the result of the previous one, it has to wait. This will eventually create "gaps" that a core is left idle waiting for a new operation is ready to be executed. Among them, device memory operations have HUGE latencies. If you don't do it right, your code will end up busy waiting for memory operations all the time.

Some tasks can be well optimized. If you test on gemm in cuBLAS, it can reach over 80% of the peak FLOPS, on some devices even 90%. While some other tasks just can not be optimized for FLOPS. For example, if you add one vector to another, the performance is always be limited by the memory bandwidth, and you can never see high FLOPS.

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer. It is much clear now.